# How to set the hide Time of the Launchbar higher?

Tags: unity, launcher

I found a duplicate of my question, but with the opposite intention.
Also, the Answer shows where the setting is, but not how to find the File
with the quoted text. Neither if it is possible to edit it.

Or does following mean that it is Impossible to alter it?

> This seems to be hard coded into the Unity source. See here on line 32:

Here is the quoted Q&A:

> [How to set the launcher hide delay time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239152/how-to-set-the-launcher-hide-delay-time)

As I am new to Linux based operating systems, I wanted to ask IF it
is possible to edit the `/launcher/LauncherHideMachine.cpp` as I can 
not even find the file...

My intention would be to change

```
const unsigned int HIDE_DELAY_TIMEOUT_LENGTH = 400
```

to this value:

```
const unsigned int HIDE_DELAY_TIMEOUT_LENGTH = 900
```

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a hard coded value.  There is no configuration option to change it.

To change it you would have to recompile the software yourself with the change you want, which can be painful and be a massive headache from a package management perspective.  There is also no guarantee that a recompiled version will work as nicely either.